# how to add variable inside php echo

Tags: php

Why is my code not working?  I am new to this. Thanks

```
<?php
echo "<iframe src='$_GET["name"]' style='border:none;width:100%;min-height:1000px;'></iframe>";
?>
```

Comment: sorry guys I am new to php

Comment: One thing to add to a question like this is what you mean by *not working*.  Any messages are useful in helping answer the question.

Comment: Your code triggers a PHP parse error. Your text editor doesn't seem to have PHP syntax features and your PHP setup is configured to hide error messages.

Answer (score 0):

When you're concatenating php code with a string you've to use the syntax
which is the dot sign " . "

so you're code should be like this:

```
<?php echo "<iframe src='".$_GET['name']."' style='border:none;width:100%;min-height:1000px;'></iframe>";?>
```

note how I switched the quote signs to make it realizable to to php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  echo "<iframe src='". $_GET["name"] . "' style='border:none;width:100%;min- 
  height:1000px;'></iframe>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use concatenation operator and if you check valua isset it would be better usage.

```php
if (isset($_GET['name'])){
    echo "<iframe src='".$_GET["name"]."' style='border:none;width:100%;min-height:1000px;'></iframe>";
}
```